# How put(pack) JPanel with chart inside JPanel which inside JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfreechart

I had method,which returns JPanel with JFreeChart with ChartActionListener.
In my test program it works well,i just write `setContentPane(createContent());` and program show it as full size JPanel.

When i create my main Frame with JPanel in a special place(i do it by NetBeans swing constructor), my JPanel could not show content, it just stays an empty JPanel.

I tried to put it like `JPanel pan = createContent();
jPanel1.add(pan);`= doesn't work.

I also tried to write : `jPanel1 = createContent();` : it doesn't work.

It only works when i write same after....`:initComponents();CrossHair cross = new CrossHair();setContentPane(cross.createContent());`

So it shows content, but other parts of my programm become unreachable..here is the method createContent:

```
    private JPanel createContent() {
        JFreeChart chart = createChart(createDataset());
        chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent event) {
             //---- to not make that code big  
        }

        @Override
        public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent event) {
             //---to not make that code big  
        }
    });

    CrosshairOverlay crosshairOverlay = new CrosshairOverlay();
    xCrosshair = new Crosshair(Double.NaN, Color.RED, new BasicStroke(0f));
    xCrosshair.setLabelVisible(true);
    yCrosshair = new Crosshair(Double.NaN, Color.GRAY, new BasicStroke(0f));
    yCrosshair.setLabelVisible(true);
    crosshairOverlay.addDomainCrosshair(xCrosshair);
    crosshairOverlay.addRangeCrosshair(yCrosshair);
    chartPanel.addOverlay(crosshairOverlay);
    return chartPanel;}
```

Thanks in advice, any example could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the difference between `ChartPanel` and `jPanel`.

I solved this by using

```
jPanel1.add(cross.createContent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```